# I want my html site to be loaded in different language

Tags: javascript, html

After some search i got this code for website translate

But what I really want is my HTML website to be loaded in danish language by default

```js
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
    pageLanguage: 'en',
    layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
  }, 'google_translate_element');
  setcookie('googtrans', '/da');
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
<div id="google_translate_element">This should be in Danish</div>
```

Comment: Please share your opening html tag and a bit more detail re what you're current html document looks like.  Also please take a look at this url => https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations.
HTH.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be two problems with your code:

- First, you don't have `setcookie` defined.
- Secondly, you're not calling your `googleTranslateElementInit` function.

To resolve the first issue, define the `setcookie` function. Here's an example that might do what you want:

```
function setcookie(name, value) {
  document.cookie = name + "=" + value + ";path=/";
}
```

Then call `googleTranslateElementInit()`.

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xjukmhgn/1/

You might want to hide the `div` until the translation occurs, but that's another topic.